# How can I find "docs" inside "android/sdk" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed "Documantation for Android SDK" in Android Studio and I want to access to Android/sdk directory and open the docs folder and then open `index.html`. But I don't find it; I checked for an access in "Android SDK" inside "Setting for New Projects". There, there're 3 menus: "SDK Platforms", "SDK Tools" and "SDK Update Sites". Where can I find the required file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you installed via SDK Manager the folder you looking for is in

> ...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\docs\reference\

[image: In this folder exists the index.html you wish]